# Run js or ts file with `bun js` in vscode's code runner extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner, bun

How can I run `.js` or `.ts` file with bun in VS Code (from Code Runner Extension). I have only `bun JS` as JavaScript Runtime in my Computer ( I don't have `nodejs` in my computer).

Even if I download `nodejs` then how can I run `.js` file with `bun js` in vscode code runner?

When I click run button in VS Code, it runs `.js` or `.ts` file with node.
I don't want to run `.js` file with `nodejs` or type `bun run myFile.js` in terminal.

I want to run the file with `bun js` with code runner extension as I do with `nodejs`.

***I am aware of bun extension in vscode by pandy. But I want this with code runner extension button.***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding

```json
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "javascript": "bun $fullFileName",
},
```

to your settings should make bun the default runner for javascript files.